# How do I configure Cabal to understand a C FFI?

Tags: haskell, build, cabal, ffi

I am trying to create a Haskell library which uses a C FFI. I have 4 files:

```
MyLibrary.hs
c_dependency.h
c_dependency.c
c_dependency.o
test.hs
```

All on the same directory. `test.hs` loads MyLibrary and tests it:

```
-- test.hs
import qualified MyLibrary as Lib
main = Lib.test
```

I want to be able to compile `test.hs` as usual, without linking to `c_dependency.o`. That is, I want `ghc test.hs; ./test` to work. How can I init/configure cabal so it builds my library properly, taking care of linking `c_dependency.o` ?

Answer (score 2):

A series of blog posts on [Cabal, the FFI, and c2hs](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/06/setting-up-cabal-the-ffi-and-c2hs/) has what you're looking for in the second article, the "Compiling the library with Cabal" section.